# Facter - No operatingsystemmajrelease in my install (CentOS)

Tags: puppet, facter

I have a weird happening on my servers:

Foreman is running as puppetmaster and is correct:

```
[root@foreman manifests]# facter | grep opera
operatingsystem => CentOS
operatingsystemmajrelease => 6
operatingsystemrelease => 6.5
```

On the two servers I have plugging in to it at the moment, the majrelease is absent:

```
[root@tool01 ~]# facter | grep opera
operatingsystem => CentOS
operatingsystemrelease => 6.6


[root@app01 ~]# facter | grep oper
operatingsystem => CentOS
operatingsystemrelease => 6.6
```

Being new to foreman/puppet, I am not sure how to go about fixing this. I found an article asking the same question, but the responses were all "It should be there", so I am sure I am doing something wrong?

Comment: For now I bypassed the problem by:
package { "redhat-lsb": ensure => installed, }

Then:
sed -i 's/operatingsystemmajrelease/lsbmajdistrelease/g' init.pp

But I would still like ot know how to fix it correctly..

Comment: Can you paste the output of `facter -d` from one of the afflicted boxen somewhere and add the link to your answer?

Comment: Certainly - http://pastebin.com/p6qJBEXY

Comment: I have facter version 2.4.6 and am seeing the same issue. I've noticed this line in `facter -d`: "Found no suitable resolves of 1 for operatingsystemmajrelease"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Facter version is ancient. Consider updating to at least `1.7`, but see if you can get `2.1` or above.